# Table of contents not working

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

My document is failing to generate a table of contents.

This is the latest MWE suggested by Nickie (perhaps messed up in translation, I don't know).  When I compile this in TeXworks using pdflatex, it does not generate a table of contents.  I put in some sample text to test that features I was using still work (like links), and they do.  But the table of contents still does not display.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{DeepPink}{rgb}{0.8,0,0.4}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{DarkBlue}}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}

\makeatletter
% copied from mwe
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
   \thispagestyle{plain}%
   \global\@topnum\z@
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

% copied from book.cls and modified
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
      \refstepcounter{chapter}%
      \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\string\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\hbox to .65in{Chapter}\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}{\thepage}}%
    \else
      \addtocontents{toc}{\string\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\hbox to .65in{Chapter}\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}{\thepage}}%
    \fi
  \else
    \addtocontents{toc}{\string\contentsline {chapter}%
      {\hbox to .65in{Chapter}\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}{\thepage}}%
  \fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
  \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
  \fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=DeepPink,linkcolor=DarkRed,urlcolor=DarkBlue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{C++ First Blood}

This is a test.

Review Questions
\begin{enumerate}
\item What color is George Washington's white horse?
\item What function is the entry point to every C++ program?
\end{enumerate}

\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory}{Graph Theory}

\chapter{Java: More Delicious than C++}

\chapter{Python Swallows Those other Languages, Whole}
\chapter{D for Those who Cannot Spell C++}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Appears this error message: ! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2 \contentsline
                  {chapter}{\hbox to .65in{Chapter}\numberline {2}ch2}{3}
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2 \contentsline
                  {chapter}{\hbox to .65in{Chapter}\numberline {2}ch2}{3}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on olatex_1151915_86EFfXpTk3Ex.log.

Comment: Considering what you now ask (about `pdflatex`) see my addition (third paragraph from the end of my answer).

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I recently encountered this problem and found that specifying the TOC option in the hyperref load solved my problem very simply: `\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the way that you redefine `\@chapter`, which is incompatible with `hyperref`.  You can see this immediately if you comment out the line loading `hyperref`, just before `\begin{document}`.

The `hyperref` package plays a lot with everything containing references; lines in the table of contents are just one such thing.  It achieves this by redefining commands such as `\addcontentsline`, effectively adding hyperlinks to all references.  After `hyperref` is loaded, the command `\contentsline` (which normally takes 3 arguments) requires also a fourth argument: the anchor where the line links to.  In your case, your definition of `\@chapter` uses `\contentsline` directly and only provides three arguments.  The fourth one will never be introduced by `hyperref`, thus latex complains that it's missing when reading the `toc` file.

An immediate solution that works is to replace the following line (occurring three times) in your definition of `\@chapter`:

```
      \addtocontents{toc}{\string\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\hbox to .65in{Chapter}\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}{\thepage}}%
```

with an equivalent one that does not explicitly use `\contentsline`:

```
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}% 
        {\hbox to .68in{Chapter}\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
```

(I changed the width here to avoid an overfull `\hbox`.)  This will give `hyperref` the chance to properly introduce the fourth argument to `\contentsline`.  Now, `hyperref` (in fact the PDF driver) will warn you that you shouldn't be using `\hbox` in content lines, but you can live with it.

Of course, to see the table of contents, you need to invoke `pdflatex` multiple times.  I recommend the `latexmk` utility: by running `latexmk -pdf yourfile.tex` your PDF will be made automatically.

I understand that the only change you want, over what `book.cls` normally does, is to introduce the word "Chapter" before chapter titles in the table of contents.  If this is so, a probably better solution would be to leave the definitions of `\chapter` and `\@chapter` untouched and to redefine `\l@chapter` (which is used by `\contentsline`) to suit your needs.

An even better solution, as you already use the `titlesec` package, is to also use `titletoc` in order to introduce the word "Chapter" in the table of contents.

Comment: Actually, I do not want the word chapter.  I just want chapter number. title. What do I do? Forgive me for my ignorance, Latex makes C++ look like child's play.  All the weird little rules, side effects, it's mind boggling to a novice!

Comment: If you don't want the word "Chapter", then just remove all customization.  Remove everything between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (including those two).

Comment: I will just have to ask a separate question about texworks, but the command is right on the windows command line.... Thanks!